# .net winforms Show Form On Top Dialog

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a form that acts as a waiting form, essentially it maximized and mostly transparent except for the center which shows a spinner animated GIF.

I also have a form that is being shown as a dialog. In this dialog's Load event, there is a long running process that is being done by a 3rd party control. So what I'm trying to do is when the dialog is loading, show the waiting form, then once it is finished, close the waiting form.

```
Private Async Sub frmFullScreen_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Using waitingDialog As frmWaiting = New frmWaiting()
        waitingDialog.Show(Me)

        await Task.Run(Sub()
                           await control.LongRunningMethod()
                       End Sub)

        frmWaiting.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

The issue that I'm running into is that the form is displayed, but I'm guessing its being shown behind the dialog because I don't ever see it.

I've tried setting the instance of frmWaiting's TopMost property to True, but this still doesn't show the waiting form over the dialog. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure whether you have seen my answer yet but I have updated it with a working code example of the suggested solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this but what if you were to design your waiting form such that it took a delegate as a constructor argument or via a property, asynchronously executed that delegate when it was displayed and then closed itself when the delegate completed? That way, you could call `ShowDialog` on the form instead of `Show` and that would likely alleviate the issue. It would probably also mean that you would not need to make a full-screen transparent form to prevent access to other forms. I'll try to put together an example.

EDIT:

OK, here's what worked for me. I created a new WinForms project with three forms. I then added a new class named `TextBoxEx` with the following code:

```vb
Public Class TextBoxEx
    Inherits TextBox

    Public Async Function DelayAndSayHello() As Task
        Await Task.Delay(5000)

        Invoke(Sub() Text = "Hello World")
    End Function

End Class
```

I then built the project, after which that `TextBoxEx` control was automatically added to the Toolbox.

I then added a `ProgressBar` to `Form3` with the `Style` set to `Marquee`. I made `Form3` quite small and enlarged the `ProgressBar` to fill most of it. I set the `FormBorderStyle` to `None`, the `StartPosition` to `CenterScreen` and added the following code:

```vb
Public Class Form3

    Public Property Method As Func(Of Task)

    Private Async Sub Form3_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        If Method IsNot Nothing Then
            Await Task.Run(Method)
        End If

        Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

I added a `TextBoxEx` control to `Form2` along with the following code:

```vb
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Using f3 As New Form3 With {.Method = AddressOf TextBoxEx1.DelayAndSayHello}
            f3.ShowDialog()
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

I added a `Button` to `Form1` along with this code:

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using f2 As New Form2
            f2.ShowDialog()
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

I then ran the project and clicked the `Button` on `Form1`. The small, borderless dialog was displayed in the centre of the screen and the `ProgressBar` scrolled. I was unable to access `Form1` while `Form3` was displayed. After 5 seconds, `Form3` disappeared and `Form2` was displayed with "Hello World" displayed in the `TextBox`.